# Unicode characters encoding in C#

Tags: c#, encoding, html-encode

I am working on a feature which contains simple save and retrive text. To prevent XS attacks I have encoded all text with `Microsoft.Security.Application.Encoder.HtmlEncode` method.

Now the problem is whenever user enters Unicode characters like `en-dash i.e. –` and `em-dash i.e. —`, after encoding &#8211 and &#8212 are shown on screen.

Now I what I tried it to write additional encoding code e.g.

```
retString = retString.Contains("&#8211;") ? retString.Replace("&#8211;", "–") : retString;
retString = retString.Contains("&#8212;") ? retString.Replace("&#8212;", "—") : retString;
```

With above fix desired output is shown on screen, but what about other unicode characters? If user enters other unicode character, system will continue to show the # equivalents of that.

How can solve this problem so that it will work for all unicode characters.

On HTML front it is a simple ASP.NET web form with a GridView containing TemplateField as:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Note">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine"
        Width="250px" Rows="4" ReadOnly="true" Text='<%# UtilsHelper.HtmlEncode(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"CaseNotes"))%>'></asp:TextBox>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: Encoder is doing is job well, problem is how you _write_ such encoded string in your HTML page. Please show that code.

Comment: Rather than creating possibly thousands more replace statements, you should consider using a different security mechanism. HtmlEncode is simply the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti added that in question, anyways its just GridView, nothing fancy there

Comment: What does UtilsHelper.HtmlEncode does? If it...double encode Microsoft.Security.Application.Encoder.HtmlEncode output then you will have literal strings